# Induced EMF of a rectangle loop?

Tags: electromagnetism

If a rectangle loop would move inside a magnetic field, would the induced $\epsilon$ be zero?

[image]

Why would it? Is it due to the induced $\epsilon$ canceling out? Being in series and in opposition?

If it we're a single wire it would have an induced $\epsilon$ = $-vBL$.

Answer (score 1):

There are forces pushing the electrons in both wires that are perpendicular to the motion. On the one side these forces try to make the electrons go clockwise; on the other side they are trying to go counterclockwise. These two forces, being equal and opposite, cancel each other out. In principle there will be a potential difference between the two sides of the wire loop, but no current flowing as long as the velocity is constant and the B field uniform.

Comment: I also looked at it as if two single wires with length $L$ moving at the same velocity direction wired, in series ,therefore, canceling each other out. $V_1 - V_2= 0$